# Django-generic-ratings installation gives error: No module named default

Tags: python, django, generics

I have installed django-generic-ratings using the command pip install django-generic-ratings as mentioned in [django-generic-ratings requirements](http://django-generic-ratings.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#requirements) But the problem is as soon as type in

```
(r'^ratings/', include('ratings.urls')),
```

to my urls.py file, django gives me an error saying '`No module named default`'. And when i remove this line from my settings.py file, it stop giving this error. Anyone know why is this happening? I desperately want to use their star-rating system in my app, but it doesn't seem to be happening :(

So, I've downloaded agon_ratings and it gives me the same error. Same issue with this? What is going on? :(

Comment: Looks like you are using django > 1.6, and the code has not been updated https://frankban@bitbucket.org/frankban/django-generic-ratings - use a more actively supported repository

Comment: Yes, I am using Django 1.7.1 . Oh, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

for linux
go to: `cd usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ratings/`
 
open: `urls.py`
change:`from django.conf.urls.default import patterns,url`
to :`from django.conf.urls import patterns,url`